# virtualization platform: Ubuntu + KVM/Xen

Tags: linux, virtualization, storage, kvm-virtualization

performance and feature set offered by the latest Ubuntu 11.04?

while it works best as virtual workstation with direct attached storage, what is the tool-stack offered for server virtualization management: VM, network and storage provisioning?

want to be using the latest Linux Kernel and Filesystems: EXT4, XFS which are not offered by 
XenCloud Platform

thanks in advance for sharing your experiences/advice

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "help provision"? libvirt contains quite a few storage related verbs, but all those require you set up the storage yourself and provide access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially, you are looking for an end to end virtualization solution, right? If that is the case, this may fit the bill:

http://www.openstack.org/